# Bind interface to concrete class with Symfony's service container

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

With C#, ASP.NET MVC and something like [Autofac](http://autofac.org/), I can create an interface `IProductService` and bind it to a concrete implementation class `ProductService` with code like this (where builder is an `Autofac.ContainerBuilder`):

```
builder.RegisterType<ProductService>().As<IProductService>();
```

Then in my controller, I can create a constructor which looks like the below:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IProductService _productService;

        public HomeController(IProductService productService)
        {
            this._productService = productService;
        }
    }
}
```

Using reflection, Autofac is able to figure out I'd like an `IProductService` implementation injected into my constructor and provide the type I registered earlier as the concrete implementation type, resolving dependencies in the `ProductService` class as necessary in order to create an instance for the controller to use.

---

I'd like to achieve something similar using Symfony. My current understanding is that I can make use of Symfony's service in the following manner:

```
services:
    product_repository:
        class: App\WebBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
    product_service:
        class: App\WebBundle\Service\ProductService
        arguments: ["@product_repository"]
    home_controller:
        class: App\WebBundle\Controller\HomeController
        arguments: ["@product_service"]
```

And then use a controller like this:

```
namespace App\WebBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private $productService;

    public function __construct(IProductService $productService) {
        $this->productService = $productService;
    }
}
```

This works, but it's far from ideal because I now not only provide the interface type-hints in the constructor (which already make it clear which service I want injected), I also have to figure out the service names and provide them in the configuration file for every class I want that uses services.

The other alternative I can see is making use of of the `get` function on `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`, like so:

```
namespace App\WebBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private $productService;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->productService = $this->get("product_service");
    }
}
```

This approach works, except I'm now completely reliant on Symfony's service container (making moving to another framework in the future difficult), my IDE has no idea what type `$this->productService` is and so I've also lost autocompletion. It's also not obvious to other developers where the service comes from, and I have to repeatedly refer back to the config file to find out which class is registered with the id of "product_service" (I can't use my IDE's navigation tools to jump to the declaration of the interface or find all classes which implement the interface).

My understanding is that Laravel's Illuminate Container component provides the functionality I'd like to achieve (using reflection to figure out which type is being hinted in a constructor/method and resolving dependencies using bindings provided by the developer) but I'm unsure if it would be possible to set up easily with Symfony. Is there any way I can achieve this functionality whilst still using Symfony (perhaps I can listen to the `kernel.controller` and do stuff there)?

Comment: The JMSDIExtraBundle might be of some use to you.. http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/usage

Comment: @Qoop Thanks for the link. The bundle is interesting and it might be more obvious to make use of the annotations instead of configuring things in a config file. It's a shame there isn't proper language support for class metadata/annotations in PHP since I don't like the current approaches (with doblock comments) too much.

Whilst the bundle seems useful for making the service registration more obvious, it doesn't appear to allow interface => class bindings from the documentation I've read so far which is the biggest thing I want to be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kévin Dunglas opened a PR adding services autowiring and it has been integrated into Symfony as of version 2.8: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15613

To achieve the goal outlined in the question, the `services.yml` file should look like:

```
services:
    product_repository:
        class: App\WebBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
    product_service:
        class: App\WebBundle\Service\ProductService
        autowire: true
    home_controller:
        class: App\WebBundle\Controller\HomeController
        autowire: true
```

The `product_repository` service is registered so that the Symfony Dependency Injection Component is aware of at least one concrete class implementing `IProductRepository`. The `autowire` property on the other services will ensure that the dependencies in the constructor are injected appropriately.

Further documentation is available [here](https://dunglas.fr/2015/10/new-in-symfony-2-83-0-services-autowiring/).

Comment: I tried to add this detail to the original answer but the edit was rejected, so I've posted it as another answer in the hope that someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the PR has now been merged. Check out the Symfony doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/autowiring.html

Autowiring is not currently supported by the Symfony Dependency Injection Component. However I've opened a PR adding that feature and if it gets enough positive feedback it will be integrated in Symfony 2.8: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15613